# Which one to use "if" or "since"

Tags: meaning

From native English speaker point of view, which sentence sounds best ?

1. If he doesn't have the money, why does he want to buy such a big car?
2. Since he doesn't have the money,  why he does want to buy such a big car?

Answer (score 1):

"Since" is asserting the condition (i.e. it is explicitly saying that he hasn't the money). "If" is not asserting: perhaps I don't know whether he has the money or not.

In either case, the "why" in the consequent triggers inversion: "why **does he want** to buy such a big car?"

Comment: ***If** it's that simple, isn't this effectively a rhetorical question?* I think in many cases, an ***if*** clause before a question really means *If we accept that this if-clause is true (which it undoubtedly is, since this **is** an embedded rhetorical question),... then **why** [blah blah]*.